# How to create Azure devops kubernetes service connection for to access private AKS cluster?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-aks, serviceconnection

Creating a service connection to access non-private AKS cluster is straight forward, however if i want to create service connection for private AKS cluster is it possible from Azure Devops?

Comment: A service connection isn't defined to connect to a particular thing. In short to get for example a pipeline to deploy to a private resource, I needed to provision a VM connected to the same VNET, install a devops hosted build agent on there and use that to connect. The MS hosted buikd agents won't be able to connect to a private resource

Comment: Yeah, i figured. So now i am using self hosted vm as devops agents with network configuration from vm to AKS cluster and using it as build agents.

Comment: This works to me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/access-private-cluster?tabs=azure-cli

Answer (score 1):

Here's the latest update from Microsoft using the `az aks command invoke` feature

```
az aks command invoke --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myPrivateCluster --command "kubectl get pods -n kube-system"
```

You can read the full article here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/access-private-cluster?tabs=azure-cli

Answer (score 0):

You can [create New Kubernetes service connection](https://colinsalmcorner.com/azure-pipelines-for-private-aks-clusters/#create-a-generic-k8s-endpoint) using the KubeConfig option and click the dropdown arrow to choose `Save without Verification`

Also see [Deploying to Private AKS Cluster](https://colinsalmcorner.com/azure-pipelines-for-private-aks-clusters/#deploying-to-private-aks)

Comment: But does communication works from Microsoft hosted agents to Private AKS using KubeConfig service connection?

Comment: Not out of the box - only if you have advanced networking skills to "white list" Microsoft hosted agents, which is NOT recommended. Your best option for Private AKS cluster is to use self-hosted agent, which is already on your internal network.

Comment: Yes. Did that in last week using VMSS hosted agent. However, there is some issue with KubernetesManifest@0 Azure DevOps task while creating the secret.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73098411/kubernetesmanifest-createsecret-fails-with-illegal-base64-data-at-input-byte-432

Answer (score 0):

Please use below link
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/using-azure-devops-to-deploy-an-application-on-aks-private/ba-p/2029630

I have impleted this solution in my place, we had private aks , we where unable to make service connection from azure devops to azure kubeneted,

we created a self hosted linux agent in the subnet where kubenetes is and add used my agent to run build and release pipeline