# KubernetesManifest createSecret fails with illegal base64 data at input byte 4329 in Azure DevOps pipeline execution

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy an application into Private AKS cluster using Azure Devops pipelines in VMSS agent.

I have create service connection with kubeConfig option ( saved without verification ) for connectivity.

**Task:**

```
- task: KubernetesManifest@0
      displayName: create secret
      inputs:
        action: 'createSecret'
        kubernetesServiceConnection: PRIVATE_AKS_SC
        namespace: 'default'
        secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
        secretName: 'mysecret'
        dockerRegistryEndpoint: 'PRIVATE_ACR_SC'
```

**Error:**

[image]

Same task works for Public AKS cluster.

Comment: The issues appears to be a config problem - not related to public/private AKS cluster. Check the encoding on your config files, especially if you have copied text from windows files etc. - check character encoding...